# How to update or insert a new values to table once the element in a table is deleted using triggers?

Tags: mysql, triggers

*Error Code: 1363. There is no NEW row in on DELETE trigger*

Once the certain league is deleted I want to insert a new league with the same fields except now the field name = 'no league' or I can just update league but I can't do it since I get errors all the time

IF i uses this query:

```
CREATE
TRIGGER delete_league
BEFORE DELETE
ON league
FOR EACH ROW
insert into league (id_league, name, competition_id_competition) values(null, 'немає ліги', old.competition_id_competition);
```

i get this error *Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'league' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.*

```
drop trigger delete_league;

CREATE
TRIGGER delete_league
AFTER DELETE
ON league
FOR EACH ROW
update league set id_league = OLD.id_league, name = 'no leagues', competition_id_competition = OLD.competition_id_competition;


delete from league where id_league = 11;
```

Akin.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE delete_league2(OLDcompetition_id_competition int)
BEGIN
    insert into league (id_league, name, competition_id_competition) 
    values(null, 'no league', OLDcompetition_id_competition);
END //

DELIMITER ;

CREATE
TRIGGER delete_league
BEFORE DELETE
ON league
FOR EACH ROW
call delete_league2(old.competition_id_competition);


delete from league where id_league = 11;
```

Comment: Move deletion logic into stored procedure. Or create event procedure which will insert needed row in the trigger.

Comment: @Akina doesn't work

Comment: @Akina check the post, I wrote what you told me

Comment: You understand me wrongly. Stored procedure must do everything - copy the row then delete. I.e. stored procedure must be called **instead of** DELETE statement, and do the work which you'd place into trigger too, so no trigger needed. Or you'd create **event** procedure which will execute, for example, a second later, and insert new row.